# Memory leak swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I am experimenting with memory leaks in Swift, and I want to clear memory when the didReceiveMemoryWarning() function gets called.

My app has a tab-bar at the bottom and every tab-bar has its own `navigationController`. From this controller, views are pushed on a stack.

If I get a memory warning I pop every view in the navigation controller (see example)

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
   super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    for var i = viewControllers.count; i > 0; i-- {
        popViewControllerAnimated(false);
    }        
}
```

All the views are successfully removed and the "root view" of each tab is shown, but the memory won’t release until I press the tab again.

Does anyone have an idea on what i’m doing wrong?

Comment: "but the memory won’t release" – *how can you tell?*

Comment: “I tested the memory usage with the IOS simulator, if I pop view which i see using navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true) the memory will decrease, if I pop them when I am in another tab it won't decrease"

Comment: @Spidfire did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, You should not pop the viewcontrollers off the stack because iOS is good at memory management and it automatically releases the views once they are not needed.

Secondly, You are receiving a memory warning because you are maybe creating reference cycles because you are using strong references to the view controllers. Try using weak references that should solve your problem.

This explains memory management in swift and also explains how reference cycles are created and how to use weak keyword to prevent memory cycles. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: “Thank you for your fast response, I read the article and it gave me a lot of usefull information. I know understand the concept about reference cycles. I couldn’t find the possible cause of this cycle. 

I don’t understand why popping in the current tab works, and from another tab doesn’t. (It seems to me that there is no cycle because popping in the current tab does work, because then this should fails too). There are also no fields in the above views classes which refers back.